# Drawing a polyline in MapsUI MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm really struggling with trying to draw a polyline in MapsUI and could really appreciate your help. The given sample on the GitHub doesn't help me at all. This is how I tried doing it:

```
InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = vm;

    var mapControl = new Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapControl();
    var map = mapControl.Map;

    map?.Layers.Add(Mapsui.Tiling.OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());

    var point = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat(15.01917, 46.58806);

    map.Home = n => n.NavigateTo(new MPoint(point.x, point.y), map.Resolutions[12]);  //0 zoomed out-19 zoomed in

    var line = new Mapsui.UI.Maui.Polyline { StrokeWidth = 150, StrokeColor = Mapsui.UI.Maui.KnownColor.Red, IsClickable = true };
    line.Positions.Add(new Position(point.x, point.y));
    line.Positions.Add(new Position(point.x + 1, point.y - 1));

    MapVi.Map = map;
    MapVi.Drawables.Add(line);
```

I was following this sample, but couldn't get it to work: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/cca555f0793ac9bf24b2f427afdbcfe0a77f366f/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.MapView/PolylineSample.cs

The map renders and moves to the right point, but the polyline is not drawing at all...
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: please provide a link to the sample you're following.  And please explain what specific problem you're facing.  Does the map render?  Does it move to the correct point?  Does it draw any line on the map?

Comment: I edited my question with extra info :)

Comment: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/issues/1666

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link posted by Jason, the `Position` should accept two parameter that is **latitude** and **longitude**.

So the easy way is to change the following line:

```
line.Positions.Add(new Position(point.x, point.y));
line.Positions.Add(new Position(point.x + 1, point.y - 1));
```

to:

```
line.Positions.Add(new Position(15.01917, 46.58806));
line.Positions.Add(new Position(20.01917, 41.58806));
```

Also, try to set `StrokeWidth = 150` much smaller. Set it `StrokeWidth = 3`  or 4.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from the constructor to the `OnAppearing()` section. In this section edit your map **and at the end** call `base.OnAppearing()`. This worked for me with .Net Version 8 Preview. Peculiar!?

```
public partial class OverviewPage : ContentPage
{
 private static int nCol;
 const int nCols = 7;
 private static readonly Color[] pathColor = [Colors.Blue, Colors.Green, Colors.DarkGoldenrod, Colors.Firebrick, Colors.Tomato, Colors.Black, Colors.Red];
 private static readonly List<Polyline> MyPaths = [];
 private Polyline MyPath = new() { StrokeColor = pathColor[nCol], StrokeWidth = 7 };
 public OverviewPage()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 }
 protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
  ShowMap();
  double bWidth = App.DisplayWidth - (App.DisplayWidth / 50.0);
  mapControl.WidthRequest = bWidth;
  mapControl.HeightRequest = bWidth;
  mapControl.MapType = MapType.Street;
  mapControl.IsZoomEnabled = true;
  mapControl.IsShowingUser = true;
  mapControl.IsVisible = true;
  mapControl.IsEnabled = true;
  base.OnAppearing();
 }

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
 mapControl.MapElements.Clear();
 MyPaths.Clear();
 base.OnDisappearing();
}

private bool ShowMap()
{
 ...   // Here polylines are drawn
}
```